# SideBar Menu doesn't show?

Tags: ios, swift, sidebar

After the login screen, i came to Home Screen using Navigation Bar. But it create some problem, if i come from login screen, then the "SideBar Menu" doesnot open in Home Screen.
If i start from Navigation Bar Screen (not from Login Screen), then it shows the "SideBarMenu".

[image: Storyboard Image]

LoginVC.swift

```
@IBAction func btnLogin()
{
       //When response if OKAY, now it goes to Visitor View Controller
       let visitorVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NavVisitorVC") as! NavVisitorVC
       self.present(visitorVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

VisitorVC.swift

```
@IBAction func btnMore(_ sender: Any)
    {
        drawerVw = DrawerView(aryControllers: DrawerArray.array, isBlurEffect: true, isHeaderInTop: false, controller: self)
        drawerVw.delegate = self
        drawerVw.changeUserName(name: "New Delhi")
        drawerVw.show()
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your storyboard flow is wrong.
Correct your flow as:

Navigation Screen -> Login Screen -> Visitor Screen

Your SideBar menu worked in this flow.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that a button is covering the one of the side menu? If yes then try to move either the "back" button of the navigation controller or the side menu button to somewhere else (the other side of the view Controller or even at the bottom)